# The case Complex Guy

Tags: discussion, homework, specific-user

I want to draw the moderators' attention towards this case and I feel it warrants a separate topic for once, considering how obnoxious the guy is becoming as well as for future reference for such cases.

[Complex Guy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/52950/complex-guy?tab=questions) has been asking questions recently about one single paper out of which he is copying the formulas and never putting any proper thought into it. Quite obviously, many of these questions especially his latest ones just involve plugging in formulas into his equations and working things out. There's nothing very deep to understand.

My take is that he's really trying to make us read the paper for him and do his work. I think he deserves more than just closing of his threads but also a serious warning.

If this thread was overreacting, I'm sure it will be closed anyway, so I don't apologize for opening it.

Comment: I guess if someone tries to ask here about every minor detail from a paper of average length, he will quickly have problems with the question quotas (the limit is 6/day, 50/month).

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I am not comfortable with such an explicit (to begin with your title) way of pointing at a specific user in a negative way. With one exception, all the threads in the specific-user tag were motivated by positive intentions.

Answer (score 15):

Somebody who needs help understanding steps in a math paper is posting questions to Mathematics StackExchange?  How dare he.  The nerve of this guy!

But seriously, if you don't like his questions, don't answer them.  Only a few have been closed, and the others seem to be well-defined, answerable questions.  There is nothing here to warrant moderator intervention.

Comment: No need for sarcasm. Of course he can ask questions. But he just opened three threads with essentially the same question. As for your advice, I did not answer his question and I won't until he puts in some work himself. He's just a lazy bum.

Comment: @Raskolnikov The duplicate questions were the first closures I see in his history, whereas moderators give warnings for 'consistently low quality questions over time.'  If he continues to post duplicates, then something will be done about it, but aside from that nothing he is doing is against the rules.  Lastly, *as a moderator*, please allow me to suggest that you do not directly slander other users in these comments.

Comment: Just a minor quibble: the paper in question is in the "High Energy Physics - Theory" section of arxiv.org. Though his questions here appear to be on the mathematical content.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. I'm overreacting. However, whoever downvoted you is reacting even more strongly than I do. This was not necessary, I just tried to explain my viewpoint to Alexander and went overboard with the slander.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: Voting (up or down) on meta can (and often does) simply express agreement or disagreement with the answer provided, and as such means something quite different from voting on the main site.  (See the [faq](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences).)

Comment: @ArthurFischer: I see. It just shows I'm not used to the meta. :)

Answer (score 9):

To add a bit to the first sentence of the second paragraph of Alexander's answer:

> If you *really* don't like his questions†, **vote to close them!**

(Though, please, each on its own merit.) A sternly worded email/message from the moderators may seem a bit authoritarian on our part without his having received any real indication of problems from the community at large. Also, if a user has consecutive closed questions (I am a bit uncertain about the exact details), the moderators will be automatically flagged and will look into the situation, making a meta-thread like this unnecessary.

[†] Meaning you *really* feel they are not suitable for math.SE.

Comment: Shouldn't that be: "If you _really_ **think MSE is not a good place for his questions**, vote to close?" Because close votes shouldn't be instigated by personal dislike, but rather by more-or-less universal standards (with freedom of interpretation, of course).

Comment: @Lord_Farin: You're right. I was trying to match the structure of Alexander's sentence without thinking too much about the implications.